# Selinium: Wait function and if condition to repeat

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

In my automation project.

Browser: Firefox

I would like add a wait function without any specific time

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7));
IWebElement query1 = driver.FindElement(By.("continue"));
```

How can  do that?

Also to verify that if another page did not load then repeat the previous function. The reason why I am doing this is because sometimes browser does not change the page. It actually stays on that same page.

Besides this is below thing possible in Selenium

1. Clear Cache and Cookie for last hour
2. Opening URL in new tab (In already opened browser rather then opening new window)

Comment: you want an infinite wait loop? here you go: while(1) {...}..why. oh .why.

Comment: @Faiz  I don't want infinite loop. Just to identify that if next page did not load then repeat some previous steps. That's it

Answer (score 1):

One thing that has worked consistently for me (regarding waits) is used in the [conductor framework](https://github.com/conductor-framework/conductor/blob/master/src/main/java/io/ddavison/conductor/Locomotive.java#L239-L263)..

Here's some pseudo-code you can attempt to recreate in C#:

```
    while (size == 0) {
        size = driver.findElements(by).size();
        if (attempts == MAX_ATTEMPTS) fail(String.format("Could not find %s after %d seconds",
                                                             by.toString(),
                                                             MAX_ATTEMPTS));
        attempts++;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000); // sleep for 1 second.
        } catch (Exception x) {
            fail("Failed due to an exception during Thread.sleep!");
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

basically this loops through the size of the selector passed, and will poll each second.  Another way you can do it, is just by conditions.

Some more pseudo-code:

```
function waitForElement(element) {
  Wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.elementIsClickable(element), 10.Seconds)
}
```

And to your questions -

> Can Selenium...
>
> 1. Clear Cache and Cookie for last hour
>      Opening URL in new tab (In already opened browser rather then opening new window)
> 2. Opening URL in new tab (In already opened browser rather then opening new window)

1. If you write your tests cases correctly by making them independent of one-another and not re-using the same browser over and over, this happens automatically.  When Selenium opens a new window, it starts fresh with an entirely fresh profile - meaning it has "nothing" in the cache from the start.
2. Selenium does not (and will never) know the difference between a tab and a window.  To Selenium, it's just a handle.

Source:

Comment: I specifically didn't want is to add either sleep or wait function. Program should wait n times till `FindElement(By.("continue"));` I can use sleep function in my program that's like a requirement.

Comment: You don't want to add a `wait`... you want the program to `wait`... I'm confused. You really don't want to wait n times... you want to wait for a period of time. The best way to do that is the second part of this answer. Using ExpectedConditions will wait for a specified time and poll to see if the condition is true every 500 ms. if you do what you are asking, your polling is going to be done 10 times in a fraction of a second. At that point, you'll be lucky if conditions changed during that time.

Comment: ExpectedConditions is definitely the preferred route. i provided an alternative that has worked for me for years :)  Also, i'm a core contributor to the Selenium project. I'd say that the most recommended way is  using expected conditions with the Wait class, however, a custom implemented ExpectedConditions to fit your personal needs

Comment: @JeffC Please understand don't get confused. And please read carefully. wait function which is `driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7));` have a timespan. My site fluctuates due to some programming. Please understand this as well that my fluctuation is not an error. That is expected. So because of that I am want is selenium to wait without timespan or in other words without any seconds to be called.

Comment: I understand what you are saying... I'm telling you that your approach is not correct. You want to wait for a particular amount of time and NOT for X times. X times takes time anyway... so you are waiting for some period of time. If you don't want to wait, then don't wait.. just check your condition and do something based on the result.

Comment: @JeffC Sorry for the delay in my comment. As I said before. My program fluctuate when I go to next page as I am select specific criteria which makes to run the query because of that it take time to load next page. There is no specific time for that I mean every time it does not take same time it takes 7 seconds sometimes it takes 1 min. So it will be tough to "ADD X TIME". And that's the reason, why I dont want to add timespan in wait. I think you got my point